# Getting Output Tensor from Frozen Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I am training a network using transfer learning. I currently have the first 70 layers frozen, and am training only on the last 10. Because of the size of my dataset, it takes 45 minutes per epoch to train. If there is a way, I would like to train 1 epoch on the whole network, get an output tensor of the last frozen layer, and input this in the training layers for how many epochs it takes.

My hope is that this will decrease the amount of time it takes to train the network because the constant layers are essentially being skipped.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3), dropout=.2)

x = base_model.output
x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=x)

for layer in model.layers[:70]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[70:]:
    layer.trainable=True
...
```

I use ImageDataGenerator for my data to import into the network.

Here is the tutorial I was following: https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-mobilenet-and-keras-c75daf7ff299

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell, why do you need this? Do you think it will increase train speed?

Comment: Yes. That is the goal

Answer (score 0):

When you set `trainable = False` to a layer, the model does not spend time on training these layers. Non-trainable layers are skipped by default.

If you want to increase the speed, make more layers non-trainable.

Also there is a chance you are train your model on CPU, which is much slower than training on GPU

Comment: I already am training on the GPU. When trainable=False, the tensors are still fed through the frozen layers, so calculations are done. They just result in the same values every time. I was hoping to avoid having those calculations

Comment: How do think, what kind of calculations are being made? The layers are frozen. The frozen layers used only for preprocessing data for trainable layers. And you can't avoid that.

Comment: To my understanding, the first unfrozen layer receives a tensor which is generated from all the frozen layers. I know their weights are frozen, but they still compute something. If data skipped the frozen layers, it would not be the correct dimensions or shape to be in the first unfrozen layer

Comment: You use these frozen layers as preprocessing. This is the only calculation they do. If you want to get rid of such calculation, remove layers. That's how transfer learning works. You can't just get frozen layer calculations for the unfrozen ones without frozen layers

Comment: I understand they are for preprocessing. I was hoping on reducing computational time by just running one epoch through frozen layers and take their output tensor and only run that output tensor through the unfrozen layers for how ever many epochs it takes to train the network